# Exponential Equation with mistaken result

Tags: complex-numbers

I'm on my math book studying exponential equations, and I got stuck on this Problem:

What is sum of the roots of the equation: 
$$\frac{16^x + 64}{5} = 4^x + 4$$

I decided to changed: $4^x$ by $m$, so I got: $$\frac{m^2 + 64}{5} = m + 4$$

working on it I've got: $m^2 - 5m + 44 = 0$

but solving this equation the roots were: $x = \frac{5 \pm \sqrt{151i}}{2}$ 
which isn't even close from the possible answers: 1, 3, 8, 16 or 20.

What's the mistake ? thanks in advance;

Comment: Those are the roots of the quadratic equation in $m$. Remember that $m = 4^x$.

Comment: but it doesn't make sense, what would I do for $4^{5±151i√2}$ ?

Comment: This is very puzzling.

Comment: 1,3,8,16, or 20 are not solutions of the original equation.

Comment: I venture to guess that there is a mistake in the book, or that you have misunderstood and/or miscopied the problem. Maybe if you tell us what book and what page, someone will be able to have a look.

Comment: Feeding it to Wolfram Alpha as http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+16%5Ex%2B44-5*4%5Ex or http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+16%5Ex%2B44-5*4%5Ex%3D0 shows no real roots and no good set of complex roots that would give a simple real sum.  So I would support Gerry Myerson's guess that there is an error in the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you copied the equation wrong.  For the equation
$$ \frac{16^x + 64}{5} = 4^x + b$$
(where presumably $x$ is supposed to be real), substituting $m = 4^x$ we get
$$m = \frac{5 \pm \sqrt{20 b - 231}}{2}$$
where we want  both solutions to be real, so $11.55 \le b < 12.8$.  Now
$x_1 + x_2 = k$ where $m_1 m_2 = 4^{x_1 + x_2} = 4^k$.  In this case
$$m_1 m_2 = \frac{5^2 - (20 b - 231)}{4} =  64 - 5 b$$
Thus if $b=12$ you get $4^k = 4$ so $k = 1$.

Answer (score 1):

$$
\begin{align}
\frac{16^x+64}{5}&=4^x+4\\
16^x+64&=5\cdot 4^x+20\\
16^x-5\cdot 4^x&=-44\\
y^2-5y+44&=0 \quad \text{for }  y=4^x\\
y&=\frac{1}{2}\left(5\pm i\sqrt{151}\right)\\
4^x&=\frac{1}{2}\left(5\pm i\sqrt{151}\right)\\
x&=\log_{4}\left( \frac{1}{2}\left(5\pm i\sqrt{151}\right)\right)\\
\sum(x)&=\log_{4}\left( \frac{1}{2}\left(5+ i\sqrt{151}\right)\right)+\log_{4}\left( \frac{1}{2}\left(5- i\sqrt{151}\right)\right)\\
&=2\Re\left(x\right)\\
&\approx 2\cdot 1.89209=3.78418
\end{align}
$$

This is the logical answer I arrived at. Is there an error in the problem itself?

It seems that this becomes a very complex problem when it is taken to the complex plane. (I have omitted those answers as a result, since I do not understand them.) Perhaps someone more enlightened than myself would elaborate.

Comment: If you wanted to allow complex solutions, you'd also have to take into account the multivaluedness of the complex log, so there would be infinitely many solutions, not just two.

Comment: @RobertIsrael Yes, that was what I was thinking. However, I do not have a scholarly understanding of those things--so I felt unsure in speaking about them. Thank you for your enlightenment.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I the options I typed, was for the sum of the roots, but even summing the two roots, it's does not make sense too.

Comment: but Robert Israel, I didn't got the $b$ in your solution, for what this stands for ?

Comment: Since the original equation doesn't work, I'm suggesting one of the numbers in it had a copying error. For no particular reason, I'm supposing it was the last $4$ that should be something else.  $b$ stands for that something else.

Comment: @aajjbb, All this aside, hopefully you have learned something enlightening. Truly, that's the entire point of a 'problem'.

Comment: @user22144 yes, I've learned a lot in this topic, as you'll can see, I'm so weak in mathematics, and I'm dealing with a lot of issues in college, so you can expect more silly questions like this, but you can bet, I'm studying, I'm doing my best; Thanks for all the answers, but it really doesn't make sense, there's no copying error in my statement;

Comment: If you made no copying error, the author of the book may have.

Comment: @aajjbb, I'm happy for you! I recommend reporting this misprint to the author--I do that whenever I encounter an error in a book.